# make a script after document.location.href

Tags: javascript, location-href

I want to add an `alert("some text")` message after `document.location.href` or some kind of related code.

ex:

```
document.location.href = "http://www.msn.com";
windows.alert("You are now at msn.com");
```

By the moment I use `document.location.href` I automatically switch site so the rest of the code isn't being done. So I would like to know if there is an other way to switch site on the same page/ not on the same page and after that put my custom code and it will be executed accordingly?

Comment: you can only execute YOUR code on YOUR page. can you go to someone else's page and use your code? no.

Comment: Unless you have control over the new page, you can't do this.  I think the closest you can come is to open the new page in a different window and then do your alert in your page's window.

Comment: Imagine someone doing this, but instead of `msn.com`, they redirect you to your bank's website and change the login form so that it sends your password to a remote server. Browsers don't allow this to happen.

Comment: [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `haschange` event:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  // your code here
});
```

See [this post](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/jquery-special-events/)